# Openstack Instances Doesnt start

Tags: openstack

Am new to `openstack` and as of now I have got my `openstack` setup done in one of `Ubuntu:14.04 VM`. Creating network and launching a new instance all is going well and on track. But the problem is am not able start any of the instances.

Whenever I try to start an instance an error pops up saying

> ERROR:YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO START THE INSTANCE

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are logged in as the user that has admin role in that project.

As a start login with your admin user and select the admin project from the dropdown menu in the top panel. Try creating an instance from the Compute tab.